# How to concatenate incoming bytes in arduino c

Tags: arduino, spi

I'm trying to get two bytes in from an SPI sensor and concatenate them (not add them or bitwise OR them). What I have: 11111 and 1111100. What I want: 0001111101111100 (8060 in decimal).

When I Serial.print(firstByte, BIN) my two bytes, Arduino seems to remove the leading 0's (probably because there is some kind of conversion going on and those 0' are do not contribute to the value of the number or something).

That's a problem for me because I would like to concatenate those two bytes including the leading 0's before converting that two-byte binary number into a decimal integer.

Does anyone know a good approach? I'm thinking storing them as a char array, but not sure exactly. In the above example, I could just manually add in a '0' but then it would really only work if those bit values never changed, and that would be a problem.

Here is my code for reference:
https://gist.github.com/vwls/852fb5c53112efc77faaecd6bffba25f

Any advice would be really helpful!

Comment: Arduino is not C and not exactly C++! So, what have you tried? where is your code? What did not work? This is no debugging service and you have to post a [mcve] **as text** in your question. No links, no images!

Comment: Sorry @Olaf was having trouble pasting code into the code formatting here so I used gist. Will do better next time.

Comment: The edit-link exists for a good reason!

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <iostream>   // only for debug output

int main()
{
    // example how to concatenate two 8 bit values into 16 bit value
    uint8_t b1 = 0b11111, b2 = 0b1111100;
    uint16_t r = (b1<<8) | b2;
    // debug output, the value is already composed in 16b "r" variable
    std::cout << int(b1) << " " << int(b2) << " = " << int(r) << "\n";
}
```

output: `31 124 = 8060`

(sorry, I don't have Arduino SDK to verify this is compilable, hopefully the `uint**` types are selfexplanatory.)

`|` is binary OR concatenating the values, `b1` is shifted by 8 bits left (`<<8`) first, to not overlap with `b2` bits.

further edit: this **is** C++ (C++11 actually). Adjust to Arduino compiler as needed. The `|` and `<<` operators are part of original C since beginning, so you have to fix only variable types, and make sure it works. Bitwise operations are the same both in C and C++.

Comment: Arduino hardly provides iostream! And any reason for the wrong conversions to `int`?

Comment: @Olaf: iostream: only for debug output (`std::cout`). `int` conversions again only debug output, to see value of bytes. I don't know what's wrong about it (`0xFE` is displayed as `254`, if you are afraid of signed bytes, `uint8_t` looks to cover that). I should have marked that std::cout line as debug cruft only.

Comment: Yes, thanks @Ped7g this works perfectly for my application. I was avoiding bitshifting and bitwise OR because I misunderstood how it could be used in this manner! Thanks for help, I tried to upvote the answer, but this was my first post and I don't have enough rep.

Answer (score 0):

If you need one 16bit wide variable, you can use for example bit shifting.
Something like:

```
uint16_t result = SPI.transfer(...);
result <<= 8;
result |= SPI.transfer(...);
```

Comment: thanks @KIIV yes that works, thanks for your response! trying to upvote, but not enough rep.

Answer (score 0):

I just wanted to point out for anyone else that encounters this. Arduino is fully C++. A few people in this thread mentioned it is not C or C++, which is wrong. The Arduino IDE passes the code through a pre-process to do a few things for you before handing it off to the C++ compiler. If you are familiar with C++, you can do a lot of things outside the Arduino IDE to accompish anything you need.

Here's a link Arduino's explanation of the preprocesing and compile process. I think it's a good idea to understand what is really going on here.

[https://arduino.github.io/arduino-cli/0.22/sketch-build-process/#:~:text=First%2C%20the%20Arduino%20development%20software,instructions%20(or%20object%20files)](https://arduino.github.io/arduino-cli/0.22/sketch-build-process/#:%7E:text=First%2C%20the%20Arduino%20development%20software,instructions%20(or%20object%20files)).

Comment: Hello, your answer seems offtopic. I suggest to remove your answer and, instead, put a comment to the question or to another answer, because yours is not an answer but a comment.

Comment: I would move it to comment but it will not let me. Maybe that's because this thred is 6 years old?